# Making font weight normal (without any formatting) using CSS onfocus selector

Tags: css

I have an input variale text with the following attributes:

```
<input type="text" style="font-style: italic; color:#808080; font-size: 16px; width: 510px;" id="categ" value="default" name="categ" onfocus="this.value = ''; this.style.color='black'; this.font_weight='normal'">
```

i want to clear the formatting style onfocus. It clears the color and text but not the italics weight. I have also tried font-weight and font.weight

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a really good practice and will quickly lead to unmaintainable code... You should define a stylesheet and use the `:focus` selector. Javascript simply should NOT tinker with CSS properties.

Comment: Something like this ?

.myDiv{
        focus: "this.value = ''; this.style.color='black'; this.style.font.font_weight='normal';
    }

Comment: No Javascript. CSS. Let me show you... Play with [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QgSxy/).

Comment: someone -1 ed this ? really ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.style.fontWeight='normal'
```

update

```
this.style.fontStyle='normal'
```

Preview >> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2h86/)
Update >> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2h86/4/)

Comment: fiddle keeps the italics...

Comment: @CodeMonkey What about showing some effort and logical thinking? :)

Comment: updated code and the jsfiddle :)

Comment: @bažmegakapa i have been trying diff properties... intellisense of phpStorm wasn't very helpful too.. thanks

Comment: @CodeMonkey You know what I mean. He already showed you how `font-weight` transforms into `fontWeight`. How difficult would it have been to guess the right form for `font-style`?...

Answer (score 2):

You want [`font-weight`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_fontweight.asp):

```
this.style.fontWeight="normal"
```

A better way to do it is to use css:

```
#categ:focus{
    font-weight: normal;
    color:black;
}
#categ{
   font-style: italic; 
   color:#808080; 
   font-size: 16px; 
   width: 510px
}
```

Comment: no bold no italics just normal

Comment: javascript style properties aren't the same as in css. they are without dash and with uppercase initial of the second word

Comment: +1 for showing the right way

Answer (score 1):

if memory doesn't fail me..

```
this.style.fontWeight='normal'
```

however as bažmegakapa said in his comment - this is really bad practice. You should rather create a listener to the onfocus event - e.g. in jquery you could use the `.focus()` method - and have a callback function to update the css of your element.

Pure css would be even better!

Comment: not working for me :(